# Group all shapes on each slide and save picture as SVG file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

On each slide I want to select all shapes then group it and save as SVG file then go to the next slide until last slide. So far this is what I have, but it won't run properly. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far

```
Sub GroupandsaveSVG()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    folderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\mySVGs\"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir folderPath
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Group
    Call .Export(folderPath & "Shape" & CStr(x) & ".svg", ppShapeFormatSVG)
    
Next
Next
End Sub
```

The svg files also error after saved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENhNW.png)

Thank you

This is what show in Notepad
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbVuo.png)

Comment: Which version of Powerpoint do you use?  Does it support `ppShapeFormatSVG`? Go to the VBA editor, open the immediate window and enter `? ppShapeFormatSVG`. If it is 6, things are okay. If it is 0 (aka it is not defined), your version of PP is probably too old. Using 0 as parameter will create a GIF.

Comment: I use Office 365 (version 2209 Build 15629.20156), I think it does support the SVG, not sure though. But I can save as SVG manually. I open VBA Editor but not sure how to do this "open the immediate window and enter ? ppShapeFormatSVG". Do I just paste it where I usually paste code and run? What I'm doing as a work around is export it to EMF and use a software to convert to SVG, but it would be nice to get it done in one go. You think I should contact their support to see what's going on if yours work just fine? May I ask what version are you using please? Thank you

Comment: Immediate Window: In VBA-environment, Use View->Immediate window or press Ctrl+G

Comment: On a sample slide, manually select all shapes. Then look at _Shape Format>Arrange_ group on the Ribbon. Is the _Group_ command enabled? If not, your code will fail. Placeholders can't be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

- Group shapes with `Shapes.Range.Group`
- Export as svg image with `Shapes.Range.Export`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GroupSaveSVG()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    folderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\mySVGs\"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir folderPath
    On Error GoTo 0
    For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With Sld.Shapes.Range
            If .Count > 1 Then .Group
            .Export folderPath & "Shape" & CStr(i + 1) & ".svg", ppShapeFormatSVG
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much the grouping work perfectly, it did save SVG file but when open the file it show error and can't see any picture.
It show this message when I try to open the svg file


This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Start tag expected, '<' not founderror on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
Any thoughts?
Thank again

Comment: I have tested the code w/o any issues. What's kind of shapes on slides? Please try to open svg with Chrome or MS Edge to validate the image.

Comment: They are just group of shapes, I tried open them on Chrome but still showing this error message. I also tried to insert the saved file back to PPT and it show, image can't be shown.
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Start tag expected, '<' not founderror on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: I put error screenshot on my original post already, thank you!

Comment: Please try: create a new presentation file, remove all placeholder shapes from active slide, insert a shape, then run the code. If the exported svg doesn't work, please open svg with Notepad, and paste the file content in OP.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with OP, what is it please?, but the svg file still not working after create all new presentation. I tried open it with notepad and it show a long paragraph of random characters. I guess for some reasons, save as SVG doesn't work with VBA (at least on my laptop-window 10). But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: OP stands for original post. The svg file should starts with `<svg`. Your error message shows the first `<` is missing. I don't think Win10 is too old to support svg.

Comment: Thank you! I already add a notepad screen shot in my post.

Comment: It is a GIF image. Change file extension name from `svg` to `gif` and open it view Edge. It should work. Another test, change `ppShapeFormatSVG` to `6`, then run the code to export svg.

Comment: But I don't want to save as gif though. The original wasn't a gif, it is just shapes, not sure why it is show as GIF image. Also I change ppShapeFormatSVG to 6 and it didn't work. Although it doesn't show the same error anymore, but it is showing this one line "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

Comment: Please try the code on other pc. Let's see if there is problem w/ your office and win.